# Bit unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, bit, monorepo

i am newbie in Bit. My project is based on Next.js withe TS. I exported some reusable components to my Bit.dev collection, but Bit says the warning bellow after the compilation

```
SyntaxError: /capsule/node_modules/@bit/xyz/dist/nav.js: Unexpected token (11:2)

   9 | 
  10 | const Nav = () => (
> 11 |   <nav>
     |   ^
  12 |     <ul>
  13 |       <li>
  14 |         <Link href="/">
```

package. json contains this:

```
 "bit": {
    "env": {
      "compiler": "bit.envs/compilers/react-typescript@3.1.57"
    },
    "componentsDefaultDirectory": "components/{name}",
    "packageManager": "npm"
  }
```

Can somebody help me with my struggling?

Comment: Probably change the filename from `js` to `jsx`?

Comment: add : import React from 'react'   to first line of your file

Comment: @CertainPerformance you were totally right. Thanks for answering :)